# ExtJS file upload field don't show correctly

Tags: extjs, file-upload, extjs3

I am using ExtJS 3.4 and I want to use fileupload in my application. My code and fileupload field screen shot are shown below. There is a problem about showing fileupload field, I couldn't solve this error. Anyone can help?

[image]

```
var uploadFormPanel = new Ext.FormPanel({
    fileUpload  : true,
    autoHeight  : true,
    height      : 200,
    bodyStyle   : 'padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;',
    labelWidth  : 50,
    defaults    : {
        anchor      : '95%',
        allowBlank  : false,
        msgTarget   : 'side'
    },
    items: [
            {
                xtype           : 'combo',
                fields          : ['id','name'],
                name            : 'fuelCompany',
                store           : comboStore,
                valueField      : 'id',
                displayField    : 'name',
                submitValue     : true,
                typeAhead       : true,
                triggerAction   : 'all',
                selectOnFocus   : true,
                allowBlank      : false,
                mode            : 'remote',
                anchor          : '95%'
            },{
                xtype       : 'fileuploadfield',
                id          : 'form-file',
                name        : 'file',
                buttonText  : 'select file',
                buttonCfg   : {
                    iconCls : 'upload-icon'
                }
            }
    ]
});
```

Comment: The `fileuploadfield` doesn't seem to be a built-in component of ExtJS 3, at least I can't find it in the docs. Is it an extension you've written?

Comment: I have edited the version of ExtJS what I used. I used this one: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/examples/form/file-upload.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can not reach css file, I put css style in jsp file where my javascript code defined my problem solved.

Comment: I am facing same problem, Could you please tell me what css you used, I am using fileuploadfield component in cq which is based on extjs.

Comment: I added this one:

`.x-form-file-wrap {
    position: relative;
    height: 22px;
}
.x-form-file-wrap .x-form-file {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    -moz-opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity: 0);
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 22px;
}
.x-form-file-wrap .x-form-file-btn {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
.x-form-file-wrap .x-form-file-text {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 3;
    color: #777;
}
.upload-icon {
    background: url('image_add.png') no-repeat 0 0 !important;
}`

Answer (score 1):

It's a little tricky, but I think I figured out how to get the button showing the text:

```
//...
{
    xtype       : 'fileuploadfield',
    id          : 'form-file',
    name        : 'file',
    buttonCfg   : {
        text    : 'select file'
    }
}
//...
```

You need to place the button text in the `buttonCfg` for the button to size correctly. The only drawback is that you can't add an `iconCls` to the button if you want it to automatically resize. As an alternative, you could use a little workaround:

```
//...
{
    xtype       : 'fileuploadfield',
    id          : 'form-file',
    name        : 'file',
    buttonCfg   : {
        // The text cfg takes html too
        text    : '<div class="upload-icon"' +
                  ' style="width: 15px; height: 15px; display: inline-block;' +
                  ' margin: 0 5px;"></div>' +
                  'select file'
    }
}
//...
```